# Anyone know how to show Checkboxes on Hover Over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a vertical list of checkboxes when hovering over a div or label (or just some arbitrary text). Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I have attached a snippet of html code that I am working with:

Label:

```
<label class="left-padding">
     <font color="black">Custom: </font>
     <select name="options" ng-model="PODOptions" ng-change="PODOptionsHandler()">
          <option value="" select> </option>
          <option value="extendedView">Show Extended View</option>
          <option value="hideView">Hide Extended View</option>
          <option value="showFilter">Show Filter</option>
          <option value="hideFilter">Hide Filter</option>
     </select>
</label>
```

List of Vertical Checkboxes to display:

```
<li>
    <center> <label>Region </label></center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.location" ng-true-value="mu" ng-false-value=""/>  1</center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.location" ng-true-value="pv" ng-false-value=""/>  2</center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.location" ng-true-value="nk" ng-false-value=""/> 3</center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.location" ng-true-value="st" ng-false-value=""/>  4</center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.location" ng-true-value="ry" ng-false-value=""/>  5</center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.location" ng-true-value="sd" ng-false-value=""/>  6</center>
</li>
<br>
<li>
    <center> <label> Type </label></center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.status" ng-true-value="prod" ng-false-value=""/>  7</center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.status" ng-true-value="dev" ng-false-value=""/>  8</center>
</li>
<br>
<li>
    <center> <label> Cluster Type </label></center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.cluster_type" ng-true-value="siri" ng-false-value=""/>  9</center>
</li>
<br>
<li class="active">
    <center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.cluster_type" ng-true-value="speech" ng-false-value=""/>  10</center>
</li>
```

Comment: I have tried to use something similar to: http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/35627/how-do-i-get-an-image-to-pop-up-when-i-mouse-over-a-word-text

Comment: Try using the new Stack Snippets feature to include the relevant code. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1

Comment: Attached relevant HTML portions.

Comment: Your markup is bleeding form many wounds. `<li>` can only be used as a direct descendant of `<ul>`, and `<br>` tags should not have a `/` inside them.

Comment: oh ok. thanks! I'll fix that.

Comment: `ng-model`... is this angular?